# Substituting HTML for placeholders in string

Tags: php, string

Is there a way that I can convert these strings into HTML tags and vice versa?

example:

```
$str = 'The^ff0000 quick brown^000000 fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
```

the output must be

```
The<span style="color:#ff0000;"> quick brown</span> fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

something like that and vice versa

Comment: No one seems to have much success answering your questions.

Comment: you should probably take the time to learn to write parsers (dragon book is nice for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only talking about a few specific codes, you could use:

```
$str = "The^ff0000 quick brown^000000 fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
$str = str_replace('^ff0000', '<span style="color:#ff0000;">', $str);
$str = str_replace('^000000', '</span>', $str);
```

or if you prefer:

```
$str = "The^ff0000 quick brown^000000 fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
$str = str_replace(array('^ff0000', '^000000'), array('<span style="color:#ff0000;">', '</span>'), $str);
```

If you wish to allow any number of color codes, you might do:

```
$str = str_replace('^000000', '</span>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('@\^([a-f\d]{6})@i', '<span style="color:#$1;">', $str);
```

For a conversion back (if you are not using any other `</span>`'s), it could be:

```
$str = str_replace('</span>', '^000000', $str);
$str = preg_replace('@<span style="color:#([a-fA-F\d]{6});">@', '^$1', $str);
```

Note that this assumes you are typing the `<span>` exactly as above, without variability in whitespace.

Comment: You have a start and an end ^ ; And what about nested ones!

Comment: Presumably he wants the ff0000 to become ff00ff if the string contains ^ff00ff. I think it's more difficult than you're making it.

Comment: That's great Brett thanks, but how about reconverting it to ^ff0000

EDIT:

Solved it already with

`$str = str_replace('</span>', '^000000', $str);`
       `$str = preg_replace('@\<span style="color:#([a-f\d]{6});">@i', '^$1', $str);`

Comment: Another question is what if a span contains parameters other than color like `<span style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;etc..."></span>`... it doesn't convert

Comment: If the color is always at the beginning, you can just remove `;">` from the `preg_replace`. If you get too complicated in your needs, you may need to go to some kind of HTML parser since regular expressions (as I am using) are not at all ideal for parsing HTML, especially if you want to handle all of the edge cases.

Comment: I see, I'll go take a look with html parsers... Thank you Brett for your time, this is a great help for me

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is a simple string replace if the ^(non-000000) value always represents an opening span tag with the hex value being the color style and a ^000000 always means a closing span tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example in which you should implement a Decorator patern (ex: make a static method and process the string using explode for instance and append the spans)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no actual closing tag, and would like ^000000 to represent the span closing tag, I'll expand on Mike's answer below.

```
$string = "The^ff0000 quick brown^000000 fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

// replace '^000000' first so we don't get false positives in the regex
$new_string = str_replace('^000000', '</span>', $string);

$new_string = preg_replace('/\^([0-9a-fA-F]+)\b/i', '<span style="color: #$1;">', $new_string);
```